# How to create a full screen notification from a service?

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have a timer which is running on a service. I'm trying for a full screen notification to be displayed on the lock screen when the timer ends but no luck. Is there any way to do it? If yes, how is that possible?

This is my notification code but of no use.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, TIMER_CHANNEL_ID_LOCK)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_globe)
                        .setCustomContentView(customView)
                        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_EVENT)
                        .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true); // NOT WORKING
```

I am getting a heads up notification instead.

Comment: Check https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive. There's a note that says "The system UI may choose to display a heads-up notification, instead of launching your full-screen intent, while the user is using the device."

Comment: But the device is in key guard locked state.